# The graph of $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ contains the points $(m,0)$ and $(n,2016^2)$. How many values of $n-m$ are possible?

Tags: functions, polynomials, contest-math

> > Let $a,b,c,m$ and $n$ be integers such that $m<n$ an define a quadratic function as $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $x$ is real.
> >
> > The $f(x)$ has a graph that contains the points $(m,0)$ and $(n,2016^2)$.
> >
> > How many values of $n-m$ are possible?

What I have attempted is this:

Considering the function: $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

then using the two points, firstly using $(m,0)$ we get $am^2+bm+c=0$ , now using the second point we get $an^2+bn+c=2016^2$

We can eliminate c by doing this:

$c=-am^2-bm$ and $c=2016^2-an^2-bn$

$ -am^2-bm=2016^2-an^2-bn$

$an^2-am^2+bn-bm=2016^2$

$a(n-m)(n+m)+ b(n-m)=2016^2$

$(n-m)(a(n+m)+b)=2016^2$

$n-m=\frac{2016^2}{a(n+m)+b}$

Now I am stuck , how should I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a,b$ and $c$ are **given and fixed** (so $m,n$ are dependent on $a,b,c$), considering the graph of the quadratic function gives that the number of possible values of $n-m$ is at most $2$.

One has to separate it into cases.

For the case where only one value of $n-m$ is possible, we have two cases :

Case 1 : $y=0$ is tangent to $y=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a\gt 0$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

$$\begin{align}&\small a\gt 0\quad \text{and}\quad b^2-4ac=0\quad\text{and}\quad m=-\frac{b}{2a}\in\mathbb Z\quad\text{and}\quad n_{+}=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-2016^2)}}{2a}\in\mathbb Z\\&\iff a\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad c=\frac{b^2}{4a}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{b}{2a}\in\mathbb Z\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{2016}{\sqrt a}\in\mathbb Z\\&\iff (a,b,c)=(k, 2mk, km^2)\end{align}$$
where $k$ is the square of a divisor of $2016$, and $m$ is an integer.

In this case,
$$n_{+}-m=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-2016^2)}}{2a}-\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right)=\frac{2016}{\sqrt a}$$

Case 2 : $y=2006^2$ is tangent to $y=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a\lt 0$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

$$\begin{align}&\small a\lt 0\quad\text{and}\quad b^2-4a(c-2016^2)=0\quad \text{and}\quad m_{+}=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\in\mathbb Z\quad\text{and}\quad n=\frac{-b}{2a}\in\mathbb Z\\&\iff a\lt 0\quad\text{and}\quad c=\frac{b^2}{4a}+2016^2\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{b}{2a}\in\mathbb Z\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{2016}{\sqrt{-a}}\in\mathbb Z\\&\iff (a,b,c)=(-k, -2mk, -km^2+2016^2)\end{align}$$
where $k$ is the square of a divisor of $2016$, and $m$ is an integer.

In this case, 
$$n-m_{+}=-\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{2016}{\sqrt{-a}}$$

For the case where two values of $n-m$ are possible, we have two cases :

Case 3 : $a\gt 0$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

$$m_{\pm}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\in\mathbb Z\quad\text{and}\quad n_{+}=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-2016^2)}}{2a}\in\mathbb Z$$
In this case,
$$\begin{align}n_{+}-m_{\pm}&=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-2016^2)}}{2a}- \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\&=\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-2016^2)}\mp\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\end{align}$$

Case 4 : $a\lt 0$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

$$m_{+}=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\in\mathbb Z\quad\text{and}\quad n_{\pm}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-2016^2)}}{2a}\in\mathbb Z$$
In this case,
$$\begin{align}n_{\pm}-m_+&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-2016^2)}}{2a}- \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\&=\frac{\pm\sqrt{b^2-4a(c-2016^2)}-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh I see, also is there any continuation from what I did?

Comment: The second one in your answer. Just as I worded it in my post.

Comment: @dydxx: You have $(n-m)(a(n+m)+b)=2016^2$, so we know that $n-m$ is a positive divisor of $2016^2=2^{10}\cdot 3^4\cdot 7^2$. So, there are $(10+1)(4+1)(2+1)=165$ possibilities. However, I have not been able to find anything helpful to continue from here. On the other hand, my method in my answer considers the graph of the quadratic function. It is very easy to see that the number of possible values of $n-m$ is at most $2$. Also, the condition for $a,b,c$ that the number of possible values of $n-m$ is $1$ has a very simple form as I wrote in my answer. (I'll add more details if you need.)

Comment: @dydxx: I added some explanations with figures.

Comment: Okay now this makes perfect sense! :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, $n-m$ is some integer divisor of $2016^2$. On the other hand, we can find suitable $a,b,c$ for *any* such $n-m$ (one of the possible options is: $a=0,\;b={2016^2\over n-m},\;c=-bm$). So to get the answer, you just need to count all divisors, which is pretty simple, given the prime factorization of the number.
$$2016^2=2^{10}\cdot3^4\cdot7^2$$
$$\tau(2016^2)=(10+1)(4+1)(2+1)=\dots$$

Comment: $a \neq 0$ since $f(x)$ is a quadratic function.

Comment: Oh, come on. Use any $a$ and $b={2016^2\over n-m}-a(n+m)$; that's still an integer.

Comment: Yeah that's really nice but one thing vexing me a lot is that if $n-m = w$ a integer and $n+m = u$ is a integer can these conclude that $n$ and $m$ is a integer?

Comment: No; consider $n-m=1$ and $n+m=2$. But who cares? We are **not** using $n-m$ and $n+m$ to find $n$ and $m$, anyway.

Comment: Yes the person who publish this problem care because he writes "Let a,b,c,ma,b,c,m and nn be integers such that m<n" in the first statment.

Comment: Sure they are. So what? I never said a thing about $n+m$. We don't use it at all.

Comment: So this answer is incomplete because it doesn't have enough details about how to rule out these chagrin cases.

Comment: There are no cases. We take some random $m$ (an integer), then use $n-m$ (a not-so-random integer, selected from the divisors, like I said above). This gives us $n$, which is inevitably an integer too.